# Be careful. The query to get the data might be unsafe so you should only refresh the workbook if you trust its source

Tags: excel-services, performancepoint

I use SharePoint 2013 and Excel Services and SSAS

I load an Excel file to SharePoint Document and then I use that in Performance Point Service to create an Excel Report. I then use this report to a Dashboard and finally deploys my Dashboard to SharePoint.

Note : I use a connection in Excel file for querying data from SSAS.

My report is like this picture :

[image]

But when I click in my Excel Object , I get this message :

> Be careful. The query to get the data might be unsafe so you should
>   only refresh the workbook if you trust its source.
>
> Do you want to refresh the workbook?

[image]

And after press the Yes button I get this error :

> The data connection uses Windows Authentication and  user credentials
>   could not be delegated.  The following connections failed to refresh:

[image]

How I can fix this error?

Comment: Can we stop this markup-madness? :P

Comment: What is markup-madness?

Comment: When you markup a lot of keywords in your posts as if they where code snippets. The only thing it leads to is lower readability of your post.

Answer (score 5):

**Explanation**

---

> There are multiple causes for this error message. The common factor
> behind all of them is that Excel Services cannot get a valid Windows
> user identity from a claims token in SharePoint. In the case of Excel
> workbooks that contain PowerPivot data, this error occurs when any of
> the following conditions exist:
>
> •The Claims to Windows Token Service is not running. You can confirm
> the cause of this error by viewing the SharePoint log file. If the
> SharePoint logs include the message "The pipe endpoint
> 'net.pipe://localhost/s4u/022694f3-9fbd-422b-b4b2-312e25dae2a2' could
> not be found on your local machine", the Claims to Windows Token
> Service is not running. To start it, use Central Administration and
> then verify the service is running in the Services console
> application.
>
> •A domain controller is not available to validate the user identity.
> The Claims to Windows Token Service does not use cached credentials.
> It validates the user identity for each connection. You can confirm
> the cause of this error by viewing the SharePoint log file. If the
> SharePoint logs include the message "Failed to get WindowsIdentity
> from IClaimsIdentity", the user identity could not be authenticated.
>
> •The computers must be members of the same domain or in domains that
> have a two-way trust relationship.
>
> •You must use Windows domain user accounts. The accounts must have a
> Universal Principal Name (UPN).
>
> •The Excel Services service account must have Active Directory
> permissions to query the object.

**User Action**

---

> Use the following instructions to check the status of the Claims to
> Windows Token Service.
>
> For all other scenarios, check with your network administrator.
>
> Enable Claims to Windows Token Service
>
> **1**.In Central Administration, in System Settings, click Manage services on server.
>
> **2**.Select Claims to Windows Token Service, and then click Start.
>
> **3**.Verify the service is also running in the Services console:
>
> **a**.In Administrative Tools, click Services.
>
> **b**.Start the Claims to Windows Token Service if it is not running.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487975.aspx

Comment: Hi ALI. I have a question here. Whenever an excel sheet (with data picked up from analysis db) is shown on an sharepoint page, then does it show the latest data whenever the entire page is refereshed? Then, what is the purpose of the 'refresh all connections' within the excel webpart?

Answer (score 3):

I fix this error with this way :

I Run as administrator in **IE** and then I go to **Central Administration**

And then I go to **Secure Store Service** ,

Then press **New**

[image]

I fill **Target Application ID** and **Display Name** and **Contact E-mail** and

select **Target Application Type** in **Group** and **Target Application Page URL** is none.

[image]

Then press **Next** button

and in new page I fill like this picture :

[image]

Then press **Next** button and in new page I fill like this picture :
(I use a user that have role System Account )

[image]

Then Press **Ok**.

And then I open **my Excel File** and in **Data Tab** in **Properties of connection** I go to **Definition Tab** and click on **Authentication Setting**

[image]

In new window I select **Use Stored Account** and write **Application ID** with name that I create in **Share Point** (OLAP).

And finally I load my **Excel File** in **Share Point Document** and my problem solved.

[image]

[This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/archive/2013/02/01/powerpivot-2013-refreshing-in-the-browser.aspx) is my source.

Comment: Had you turned on the:  Claims to Windows Token Service?

Comment: @ variable : I don't really remember but I don't think so.